# Spring Security: How to get the initial target url

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using the spring security to restricted urls. I am trying to provide signup and login page, on the same page.

On login spring security transfers to the restricted page. However i am trying to pass the target url to the signup process, so that after signup we can redirect to the restricted page.

How to get the actual URL that user was redirected from.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have spring 3.1.1.RELEASE configured and tried using the solution posted by you guys but somehow i get session as `null`. Any idea about probable reason for this behavior??

Comment: try `SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");`

Comment: Try this one:
SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how i got the URL from the Spring Security.

```
SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest)session.getAttribute(
    AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY);
String requestUrl = savedRequest.getFullRequestUrl();
```

Answer (score 15):

They moved things around a bit in spring security 3.0, so the above code snippet doesn't work anymore.  This does the trick, though:

```
protected String getRedirectUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session != null) {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST);
        if(savedRequest != null) {
            return savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        }
    }

    /* return a sane default in case data isn't there */
    return request.getContextPath() + "/";
}
```

Comment: As a note, WebAttributes isn't available until 3.0.3

Comment: `WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST` no longer exists in 3.1, however [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5389357/535646) works.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST can be replaced with the string "SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST" in Spring 3.1 which makes the above solution functional again.

Comment: any idea what (where?) sets this `"SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST"` session attribute?

Comment: btw, the constant is org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.SAVED_REQUEST

Answer (score 5):

with spring security 4.1.4:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
    if (savedRequest != null) {
        response.sendRedirect(savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
    }
    else{
        response.sendRedirect("some/path");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = (DefaultSavedRequest)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");

String requestURL = savedRequest.getRequestURL();   // URL <br>
String requestURI = savedRequest.getRequestURI();   // URI
```