# Get original request url in Spring Security form-login page

Tags: spring-security

I have the following declared in my spring security configuration file (http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd):

```xml
<form-login login-page="/login.html" />
```

What Spring Security does is redirect the user to that page if they don't have the correct authentication credentials. How can I get the url of the page the user was trying to get to?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631217/spring-security-how-to-get-the-initial-target-url

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Original request is represented by the [`SavedRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/SavedRequest.html) object, which can be accessed as a session attribute named `SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY`.

Comment: Looking at the docs you link to it says 'since 3.0'. I'm using Spring Security 2 (as mentioned in the question). Do you know if this will still work?

Comment: @Adbullah: I think in Spring Security 2 it work the same way: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ui/savedrequest/SavedRequest.html

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I think I've been asking the wrong question for what I want to do, check out the new question if you have a chance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696905/make-spring-security-add-the-return-to-url-in-the-query-string-for-the-login-page

Answer (score 2):

in my case i did something like this and it worked for me.

```
@Autowired
private LoggedUserListener loggedUserListener;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/find/**","/","/Application/**")
    .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    .successHandler(loggedUserListener)
//some other stuff
}



@Component
public class LoggedUserListener implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");

    if(savedRequest != null) {

        User u = userRepo.findByUsername(authentication.getName());

        u.setLastLogin(new Date()); 
        u.setAccountNonLocked(false);

        userRepo.save(u);
        response.sendRedirect(savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security 4

The original request is represented by the **DefaultSavedRequest** object, which can be accessed as a session attribute named **SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST**.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(HttpSession session) {
    DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = (DefaultSavedRequest) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");
}
```