# Make spring security add the return to url in the query string for the login page

Tags: spring-security

Earlier I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684323/get-original-request-url-in-spring-security-form-login-page) if it was possible to get the original request url in the form login page in Spring Security 2. Turns out that actually won't help me, what I need is for the redirect to the form-login page to have that embedded in it as a request parameter. So if I have:

```xml
<form-login login-page="/login.html" />
```

and try to access `/secure.html` I want to end up in `/login.html?return_to=/secure.html`.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087954/spring-security-how-to-add-a-redirect-query-parameter-to-the-login-url-to-allow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The redirect to the login form is performed by the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. For Spring Security 3.0+ this will usually be an instance of `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`. In 2.0 the corresponding class is `AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint`.

The entry point is invoked by the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` which is also responsible for caching the request. You can therefore write a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` which redirects to the login page URL with the additional parameter appended (containing the current request URI). The code should be almost identical to the standard implementation.

You can inject a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint into the namespace configuration using the `entry-point-ref` attribute on the `http` namespace element. If you are using plain beans, you would inject it into the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`.

Comment: This sounds like the right answer, I was headed down this path but something didn't seem to work for me. Sounds like I need to give it another shot.

Answer (score 10):

I guess you need to use [spring-security-redirect](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=65123).  Essentially, if your url is of the form `/login.html?spring-security-redirect=/secure.html`, spring security will automagically redirect to secure.html on successful login.

As of spring 3.1.x this no longer works out-of-the-box. You'll need to add:

```
authentication-success-handler-ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
```

...to your <form-login> element and add a bean that looks like:

```
<!-- Emulates the functionality of spring security 3.0.x by specifying the targetUrlParameter to be the value it
    defaulted to in 3.0.x. As of 3.1.x this is null by default with no option to specify in <form-login> -->
<beans:bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="useReferer" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/account"/>
    <beans:property name="targetUrlParameter" value="spring-security-redirect"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: I don't want to go there **after** login, I want to go to the login form with that url appended as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own login page and want to use the approach Raghuram suggested you must also put a hidden field with the name of the *targetUrlParameter* in the form.

For your example (ie. using *return_to* URL parameter) it would be something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="spring-security-redirect" value="<c:out value="${param.return_to}" escapeXml="true" />" />
```