# how to extend LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint or how to implement AuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to do this: [Make spring security add the return to url in the query string for the login page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4696905/) , that is: get spring to tell the login page where I came from.  I have some SSO integration.. so I'll send the url to them, or they'll append the referer for me, so I know that the user should be logged in and sent to `/some/url`.  That's all dandy.  The issue I'm having is in extending `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` (unless you can tell me a good reason to implement `AuthenticationEntryPoint` instead).  I need to only modify requests to the login page, like so:

```
RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

// only append returnto to '/login' urls
if(request.getServletPath() == "/login") {
    // indicates we want to return to this page after login
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login?returnto=" + request.getServletPath());
}
```

How can I let the rest of the requests do their thing? This is incorrect (what I was just doing):

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login");

// just forward the request
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

because it puts us in a redirect loop.  However it seems to be [what spring does in its version of `commence`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java#109).  I'm confused.  What am I supposed to be doing with `commence` in my custom extension to `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out.  Just needed to forward to the login page with 'returnto' appended.  I found it confusing at first because `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` didn't mean 'this redirects users to the login page' at first glance.  This is all I needed:

```
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login?returnto=" + request.getServletPath());
}
```

this was useful: [LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java on grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java#109)

Answer (score 0):

Josh's code was exactly what I needed to catch AJAX authentication errors in JavaScript, while still preserving the default login redirect logic for all other requests. Since all my AJAX requests start with "/rest", I was able to filter on this.

```
if(request.getRequestURI().contains("/rest/"))
    response.sendError(403);
else
    new DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/login");
```