# Spring Security - Retaining URL parameters on redirect to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

ok.

lets say I have a secure url pattern

```
/secure/link-profile
```

optionally, there can be url paramaters appended.

```
/secure/link-profile?firstName=Bob&secondName=Smith&membershipNumber=1234
```

how can I make it so that those url params are carried over to the login page?

```
/login?firstName=Bob&secondName=Smith&membershipNumber=1234
```

the basic premise is that we offer rewards integration with a 3rd party, who will send their users to us. They will be taken to a page to link their 3rd party account/profile with their/our website user. If however, they dont have an existing account with us, then on the login page, they will go to the signup page, and we would then like to prepopulate some of their details that the 3rd party has passed on to us.

thanks in advance

spring security 2.0.7.RELEASE
spring framework 3.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Can you use spring security 3.1?

Comment: as Maksym I advise using the same version of spring-security as your spring-framework.

Comment: @MaksymDemidas yes, I could potentially upgrade to spring security 3.1.

Comment: IMO the versioning of spring security being inline with spring framework is just convenience. there is no need to keep them on the same release train, unless of course you want to use a higher version of spring security, then a higher version of spring framework is required, not the other way round

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the method `buildRedirectUrlToLoginPage(HttpServletRequest request, ...)` in `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, I think it should be enough to override this method in a sublclass, copy the original method, but additionally call 
`urlBuilder.setQuery(request.getQueryString())` when it builds the url.

Then you only need to configure the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` with this customized entry point.

Comment: great idea. I already implement a `AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint`

Answer (score 5):

as per @zagyi's response I just overrode a method in my existing extension of `AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint`

the method to override is `protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception)` which is called by `buildRedirectUrlToLoginPage(..`

```
@Override
protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) {
    String url = super.determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(request, response, exception);
    return url + "?" + request.getQueryString();
}
```

obviously that could be improved to also use a builder of sorts, catering for an existing query string on the url, but at this time I know my login url is always `/login/`, so this is fine for my purposes

Comment: Thanks a lot! Made a little variant of your code with '?' detection and if already present then --> return url + "&" + ...

Answer (score 5):

A different [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405831/how-to-extend-loginurlauthenticationentrypoint-or-how-to-implement-authenticatio) explains how overriding does not work. I needed to override [commence](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html#commence(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException). This may perhaps be a new thing that was introduced in later versions of spring security.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.
    formLogin().loginPage("/signIn").permitAll().
        and().
            authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers(managementContextPath + "/**").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().withObjectPostProcessor(objectPostProcessor).
        and().
            csrf().disable().
            contentTypeOptions().
            xssProtection().
            cacheControl().
            httpStrictTransportSecurity().
        and().
            requestCache().requestCache(new RedisRequestCache(savedRequestRedisTemplate())).
        and().
            sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy).
        and().
            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint("/signIn"));
    }
}
```

```
public class AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    public AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, getLoginFormUrl() + "?" + request.getQueryString());
    }
}
```

Rizier123, thanks again for your pointers.

Comment: nice approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hi [kabal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818316/kabal) -

I have very similar requirements, and I followed yours and [zagyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276804/zagyi)'s and [lion's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1037210/lion) post, but I still seem to loose the original request parameter on /login page.

Here's what I have:

```
public class AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) {
        String url = super.determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(request, response, exception);
        return url + "?" + request.getQueryString();
    }
}



protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.
    formLogin().loginPage("/signIn").permitAll().
        and().
            authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers(managementContextPath + "/**").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().withObjectPostProcessor(objectPostProcessor).
        and().
            csrf().disable().
            contentTypeOptions().
            xssProtection().
            cacheControl().
            httpStrictTransportSecurity().
        and().
            requestCache().requestCache(new RedisRequestCache(savedRequestRedisTemplate())).
        and().
            sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy).
        and().
            addFilter(new ExceptionTranslationFilter(new AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint()));
}
```

I can see that AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint is deployed, but it does not hit a breakpoint there.

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#exception-translation-filter), it appears that this will kick in only when there is AuthenticationException or AccessDeniedException. In the configuration above, I am not sure if the spring internally throws such exception when such happens.

Additionally, I'd like to to preserve the query parameter on the landing page regardless authentication succeeds or not.

I did add success and failure handler, but none would kick into action.

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.
    formLogin().
        successHandler(new PropogateQueryStringAuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl()).
        failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl(new QueryStringPropagateRedirectStrategy())).
    and().
        authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers(managementContextPath + "/**").permitAll().
        anyRequest().authenticated().withObjectPostProcessor(objectPostProcessor).
    and().
        csrf().disable().
        contentTypeOptions().
        xssProtection().
        cacheControl().
        httpStrictTransportSecurity().
    and().
        requestCache().requestCache(new RedisRequestCache(savedRequestRedisTemplate())).
     and().
        sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy);
}
```

I am using spring-security 3.2.4.RELEASE on spring boot 1.1.6.RELEASE(which in turn uses Spring framework 4.0.7.RELEASE)

Thanks, 
San

Comment: have you added a call to `.authenticationEntryPoint(yourEntryPoint)`? my implementation for was with a very old app, and this was using xml config, and spring security 2.0.7.RELEASE

Comment: Hey @kabal Yes I tried that in following ways - httpSecurity.
    formLogin()....addFilter(exceptionTranslationFilter()) and formLogin()....authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint())

Comment: stackover-ers I just posted the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27559666/3713971) that worked for me with spring-security 3.2.4.RELEASE on spring 4.0.7