# Recover, after login, user entered values before login,

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I am developing a Spring app (even with Spring Security) where user scan a QR code which is validated and then they are redirected to login. The case is, I want to keep the QR value after login. Keep in session is not an option because session is recreated after login. So, please enlighten me. Regards,

Comment: Are you calling `session.invalidate()` after login? because then only session will get re-created otherwise session is created at the very first request to app server.

Comment: You only have to add an attribute in already created session.

Comment: Thanks Amogh I will give it a try. If it works I will accept you response.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, wise people. I am a mobile developer, so backend is not my expertise camp. I can't understand why somebody disqualifies my question. And it would be interesting that he/she leave some explanation. Nowadays Stackoverflow seems as a be a hostile place where people should be scared to ask.

Comment: I think you have to pass the validated QR code to the login page and use it in a hidden input in the login form. It then can be processed by authentication provider when login form is submitted. Search SO for how to do it such as this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282569/spring-security-retaining-url-parameters-on-redirect-to-login