# Spring Security - redirect to specific url after intercept-url access fails

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have these rules to access pages in my app:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- NON AUTHENTICATION PAGES -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/about" access="permitAll" />       

        <!-- LOGIN FILTER -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="!isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="!isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="!isAuthenticated()" />

        <!-- RESOURCES AND OTHER URLs FILTER -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <!-- FORM LOGIN -->
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/upload" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"  />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>
```

and what I need is to redirect to some url (e.g. /access-denied) when access fails and handle this event in controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/access-denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDenied(Model model, RedirectAttributes ra) {

    // do what I want

    return "redirect:login";
}
```

For example user enters /upload and he is not logged in so it will be redirected to /access-denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to explain why you need to do the redirect yourself, since Spring Security will do this automatically. When access is denied, the default behaviour for an unauthenticated user, is to redirect them to the login page (which seems to be what you want to do).

If you want to customize the process, the strategy used is the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` it would probably make more sense to implement this than to use a controller. I've written more about this in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729554/241990).

If you just want to slot in some extra functionality, you can extend [LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java) and override the `commence` method, calling the superclass to do the redirect.

Note that this means the `login-page` value from the namespace element won't be used. You'll need to set the login URL in the constructor for `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Comment: Yes, Spring security redirects to login page automatically. I want to show flash message in login page that user has to be logged in. If I want to show flash message in redirected page I can use RedirectAttributes - e.g.: ra.addFlashAttribute("errorMsg", "You are not logged in."); return "redirect:login";

Comment: Well, Spring Security doesn't know anything about Spring MVC in practice, so you can't do this in an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. You can do a double redirect (first to your controller, then to the login page) or you can manipulate the flash scope settings yourself if you are really set on using them. Alternatively, you can use a simpler method for setting the error message, such as by adding a parameter to the redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `access-denied-page` attribute in `security-http` in code that follows.

```
<security:global-method-security
            pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
            disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            access-denied-page="/access-denied">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/someurl"
                access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```