# Save target url before login?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Our Spring MVC application is using the following form-login configuration:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?failure=true" login-processing-url="/login/process"
            username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password"
            always-use-default-target="false" default-target-url="/welcome" />
```

When users access a protected url, this setup makes them login before redirecting them to that url. But if new users arrive at the login page, they click on a link to create a new account, after which they get redirected to the welcome page (as expected).

How do I save the original target url when creating a new account and redirect them to that target after creating their account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do this: [Make spring security add the return to url in the query string for the login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696905/make-spring-security-add-the-return-to-url-in-the-query-string-for-the-login-pag/4729554#4729554)

Add a bean and associate with `entry-point-ref` in `security:http`. Make the bean extend `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` and override `commence` method to save the request URI in session

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a bean such:

```
 @Component
 @Scope("session")
 class sessionPath{
 String path;
 //setter getter
}
```

and save current path in each controller;
use it any place that you want.
If you don't like to code in every controller ,you can use Aop join point to automaticaly save user last session.
Also add trigger to create new user controller to invoke session and redirect her.

Comment: But the controller is never invoked before redirecting to the login page. We use <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure" access="USER" />  to restrict access