# Spring Security 3 Get Initially Requested URL

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to modify my spring security login page based on where the user came from. My client wants the styles different between the two.  If you come from `appcontextroot/test` vs `appcontextroot/choose`. I tried to do the below but the `String url=savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();` is equal to the spring login page already and not the initial page requested by the user. Any ideas?

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesUtils.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)externalContext.getRequest();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session != null) {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(request, new PortResolverImpl());
        String url=savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
    }
```

Comment: I think you must create two different login page, with corresponding filter.

Comment: Alois, thanks for responding, do you know of an example of doing such.  I'm new to spring security...thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to extract `SavedRequest` from the session, not to create a new one:

```
SavedRequest savedRequest = 
    new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I can't find the proper key.  I've tried request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST); I'm using spring security 3.1.0.M1

Comment: @c12: Don't do it manually, use `HttpSessionRequestCache`, as shown above.

Comment: There's so much other stuff in HttpSessionRequestCache - it looks like something that should be an injectable bean, not some helper you have to new up!

Answer (score 5):

```
SavedRequest savedRequest =
    (SavedRequest)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");
// ...check for null...
String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
```

Ugly but working, if you don't have the HttpServletResponse available (e.g. in case you use `org.springframework.social.connect.web.SignInAdapter`).

Tested with Spring Security 3.1.0.RC2.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make it work with the solution proposed, here's what i found :
(Using spring 3.1).

In your fitler class :

```java
CharsetFilter implements Filter {
    @OVerride public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest hsr = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if (hsr.getUserPrincipal() == null) {
            HttpSession session = hsr.getSession();
            if (!(hsr == null)) {
                logger.info("path : " + hsr.getPathInfo());
                session.setAttribute("beforeLoginUrl", hsr.getPathInfo());
    }
  }
}
```

Then i your web.xml declare your filter :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ent.foo.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Then in your redirect url after successful login just get the HttpSession back :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "successful")
public void showSuccessfulogin (HttpSession session) {
    String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("beforeLoginUrl");
    if (redirectUrl != null) {
        session.removeAttribute("beforeLoginUrl");
        return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Here you got the stuff to make it work, but **you'll have to check the**

```
hsr.getPathInfo()
```

**and see if it ends with .css or .js, etc...**

**Also if the login fail you'll should see if session attribute is already set and see any others special case !**

Btw my filter was used before to format all input/output in utf-8.

Hope it'll help any.

Comment: You shouldn't use the filter for static resources, this will hit performance heavily.

Comment: Could you be more precise ?

Comment: In general you put your static files in either a directory with anonymous access, or on an entirely different server which has no security on it. only static resources which are truly a security concern (ie. not css or js) should be protected by security.

otherwise you are doing all of this processing (and more that you dont see) for every static resource request when it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

For me I used Spring Security 3.0.0 and the following worked :

**DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest=(DefaultSavedRequest) request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY");
        targetUrl=savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();**