# How to get SavedRequest in Spring Security 3.1.1?

Tags: spring-security

My example is

```java
SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) httpRequest.getSession()
       .getAttribute(AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY);
```

but this doesn't work in SpringSecurity 3.1.1

Comment: I haven't tried, but: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5389357/322166

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I can't find the property key `WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST`

Comment: but you don't need that property, i think, you just need to call getRequest method on HttpSessionRequestCache: `new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response)`

Comment: For those who still want to use a property, the replacement seems to be: HttpSessionRequestCache.SAVED_REQUEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest)httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute(AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY);
```