# Spring security redirect to incoming page after registration

Tags: spring-security, redirect

When you are visiting a  spring web app that uses spring security, if you are already logged in you will go to the page.

If you are not logged in, you will be forwarded to the login url. After you login you will get send to the original url.

I'd like to have the same experience for users that do not yet have an account. That is, you visit the application, it forwards you to the registration page, once you fill out the form you are sent to the page that you first attempted to visIt.

any ideas?

Comment: duplicate.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631217/spring-security-how-to-get-the-initial-target-url