# Custom login page with Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm doing a Web application using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, JSF 2.x, JPA 2 with Hibernate Provider. I use PrettyFaces 3.3.2 for friendly URL. The application run on Tomcat 6.35 .

My pages on my webapp are restricted by using Spring security 3.1.0.RELEASE.

*security-app-context.xml:*

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

<!-- login -->
<form-login login-processing-url="/login_check" login-page="/login"
    default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"
    authentication-success-handler-ref="frontConnectionHistoryHandler"  />

<access-denied-handler error-page="/accessdenied" />


<!-- logout -->
<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout_success"
    logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

<session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
</session-management>
```

*pretty-config.xml:*

```xml
<!-- Login -->
<url-mapping id="login">
    <pattern value="/login" />
    <view-id value="/login.jsf" />
</url-mapping>

<!-- Access denied -->
<url-mapping id="accessdenied">
    <pattern value="/accessdenied" />
    <view-id value="/accessdenied.jsf" />
</url-mapping>

<!-- Logout -->
<url-mapping id="logout">
    <pattern value="/logout" />
    <view-id value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</url-mapping>

<!-- Logout successed -->
<url-mapping id="logout_success">
    <pattern value="/logout_success" />
    <view-id value="/logout_success.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

Most of the time the user access the webapp like this:
`http://mysite/home/en/siteId`. The last parts of the URL is the lang / a site Id.

But if they are not connected, spring security redirect them on the login page.

I would like to display special element on the login page depending of the url asked: the last parameter `en/siteId` (lang and the site id)

For example I would like to display the logo in the login page depending of the site id.

How I can do that?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631217/spring-security-how-to-get-the-initial-target-url